# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException' exception. Cannot evaluate mypackage.MockedService$MockitoMock$980936084.toString()

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am working on the MVC tests for the Spring Boot app.

I have a weird exception being thrown by Mockito.

My code

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class, secure = false)
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private MockedService mockedService;

    @Test
    void post() {

        Dto dto = createDto();

// this code throws the exception
        when(mockedService.save(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(new MyArgumentMatcher())))
                .thenReturn(dto);


        mockMvc.perform(post("/api").content(
                asJsonString(preparePost())
        )
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

private static class MyArgumentMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<Dto> {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Dto dto) {
            return dto.getField1().equals(FIELD1_VALUE) &&
                    dto.getField2().equals(FIELD2_VALUE) &&
                    dto.getField3().equals(FIELD3_VALUE) &&
                    dto.isField4() == FIELD4;
                
        }
    }
//...
```

I have never seen such behavior from Mockito.
Adding custom `toString()` was never a requirement by Mockito and I even if I do so - nothing changes.

What's the problem here? I have no idea.

Comment: What is in `MyArgumentMatcher` ?

Comment: and also can you add the complete error message with stack trace ?

Comment: @Deadpool I don't have it, all exceptions in the methods annotated with @Test get translated to `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>`. I can only see this exception as the value of a mock in the runtime across those exact lines.

Comment: @Deadpool During debugging.

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt I put it just recently and I had this error previously without it when I had `Dto` as a parameter, this is just a standard custom matcher. I added it.

Comment: @improbable Main question seems to be where the `toString()`call is made. Any ideas? Something in `Dto` maybe?

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt This is just a standard data class with equals and hashcode overriden, no toString is used inside.

Comment: So funnily enough, whenever I comment out mockmvc call - mockito works as expected.